# Open RIA domain Service Not creating RiaDomainService metadata file

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm creating a Open RIA Domain Service. My Project configuration is like this

Hpm.DomainModels
 contains edml file , entities
hpm (silverlight)
hpm.Web
 - Domain Services

My project is in Silverlight 5 , Entitiy framwork 6 & Open RIA Domain Services.

is it a bug? How to fix it? When I test with default project & created edml in same Hpm.Web project then It created doaminservice.metadata.cs file too when DataContract etc was there.